# Session.removeAttribute is not working as expected

Tags: ignite

[Sample project showing issue](https://github.com/daynok/ignite-webapp)

What I'm noticing is that  session.removeAttribute doesn't really remove the attribute, it only sets the value to null.

I'm not sure if this is a setup issue on my end or what.

I thought this might be related to jsf, removed jsf and the issue persists.

Really want to use ignite but am struggling to get this working correctly.

Any input would be helpful, has anyone else seen this?

Thanks in advance, could use some help!  If anyone has any idea's please let me know and thank you.

dshaw

The closest issue that I could find to my particular issue was:
https://github.com/apache/ignite/pull/2243

I patched my local ignite repo with #2243 , redeployed to tomcat and 2
ignite nodes but am seeing the same issue.

My setup (client/server):

- Ignite 2.5.0 (2 node cluster)
- Apache Tomcat 7
- Java 9

tomcat 7 setenv.sh

```
#!/bin/sh 
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/java/jdk-10.0.1 
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH 
export CATALINA_OPTS="--add-exports java.base/jdk.internal.misc=ALL-UNNAMED 
    --add-exports java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED 
    --add-exports java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver=ALL-UNNAMED 
    --add-exports jdk.internal.jvmstat/sun.jvmstat.monitor=ALL-UNNAMED 
    --add-modules java.xml.bind" 
export CATALINA_HOME=/opt/apache/apache-tomcat-7.0.86_node
```

Config use by 3 tomcat nodes

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!--
  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

       http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
-->

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">





<!--
        Alter configuration below as needed.
    -->
    <bean id="grid.cfg" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
      <property name="clientMode" value="true"/>

      <property name="discoverySpi">
    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
      <property name="ipFinder">
        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.vm.TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder">
          <property name="addresses">
            <list>
              <value>172.24.2.156:47500..47509</value>
              <value>172.24.3.28:47500..47509</value>
            </list>
          </property>
        </bean>
      </property>
    </bean>
  </property>
   </bean>
</beans>
```

tomcat web.xml snip

```
 <listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.ignite.startup.servlet.ServletContextListenerStartup</listener-class>
</listener>

<filter>
    <filter-name>IgniteWebSessionsFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.ignite.cache.websession.WebSessionFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<!-- You can also specify a custom URL pattern. -->
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>IgniteWebSessionsFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<!-- Specify Ignite configuration (relative to META-INF folder or Ignite_HOME). -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>IgniteConfigurationFilePath</param-name>
    <param-value>config/client-config.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Specify the name of Ignite cache for web sessions. -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>IgniteWebSessionsCacheName</param-name>
    <param-value>medata-replicated</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Config used by 2 ignite nodes

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" 
       xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">
    <!--
        Alter configuration below as needed.
    -->
    <bean id="grid.cfg" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">

        <!-- Enable cache events. -->
        <property name="includeEventTypes">
                <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVTS_CACHE"/>
        </property>

        <property name="cacheConfiguration">
            <list>
                <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">
                    <!-- Cache name. -->
                    <property name="name" value="medata-replicated"/>
                    <!-- Cache mode. -->
                    <property name="cacheMode" value="REPLICATED"/>
                </bean>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="discoverySpi">
                <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
                        <property name="ipFinder">
                                <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.vm.TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder">
                                        <property name="addresses">
                                                <list>
                                                        <value>172.24.2.156:47500..47509</value>
                                                        <value>172.24.3.28:47500..47509</value>
                                                </list>
                                        </property>
                                </bean>
                        </property>
                </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue is also discussed on Apache Ignite user forum: http://apache-ignite-users.70518.x6.nabble.com/Session-removeAttribute-is-not-working-as-expected-td21762.html